# What should I use for a throwaway electronic prototype?

Tags: chat, user-interface

We have a project for a course where we need to implement a use case(called "Chat interaction") of a bigger project. The project represents a web interface for participants at the 4 day race in Nijmegen.

Besides other things, the interface should contain a chatting service, where you can send messages(and also pictures and videos) and they appear in a chat; you can "filter" the messages by selecting a filter, and the ones which are according to said filter will show bolded + some other small interactions.

I have experience with Java and have worked with Java Applications. The interface just needs to simulate the working project, reason for which the course lecturer said we could also use PowerPoint and their hyperlinks to "make it look like it works". I have tried the mainstream web page creating service and they are no good; Justinmind seems promising but I can't get it to work. Maybe Java application would be simplest but I am looking for something that would maybe take less time.

Comment: When in doubt, go with what you already know?

Comment: I am but currently I have problem with how containers look and how some components don't do what I expect them to..

Comment: Find yourself a WYSIWYG drag & drop GUI designer; have it generate HTML (and CSS), and clicking links should open them just as well as PowerPoint would. ***BUT***, you haven't told us why you don't want to do as the lecturer suggested (and probably expects), and use PowerPoint. Why take the extra effort when he has given you the solution as to choice of tools?

Comment: Because we need to write messages in a text box/ text field and i am not aware that there is any way to input information in the PowerPoint in the slideshow

Comment: Then ask your lecturer why he suggested doing that. All that I can think of is that PowerPoint has "export to HTML" and you need to add more code from there. But, rule #1, if the assignee is unclear, ask the one who gave you the assignee for clarification